# Add text in the middle of an image without blurring it

Tags: html, css

I'm having some problems with putting a string of text on a background image. I want to blur the image without blurring the text. But if I do that, the margins of the text are relative to the page and not to the image. So if I open the site on my phone the text is not in the middle of the image. But in the middle of the site.

```css
.bg-image {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/vKb4qnU.jpeg");
  width: 101%;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  filter: blur(4px);
  align-content: center;
}

.bg-text {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048);
  /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-image"></div>

<div class="bg-text">
  <h1>Project PP</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```css
    .bg-image {
      margin-left: -10px;
      filter: blur(4px) grayscale(.1);
      align-content: center;
        /* add a opacity here for the background */
      opacity: 0.5;
    }

    /* Centered text */
    .centered {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      font-size: 40px;
      color:#2c3e50;
      border: 6px dotted #2c3e50;
      padding:10px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/vKb4qnU.jpeg" class="bg-image" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
      <div class="centered">Project PP</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest that you use position attribute with transform just to center elements, you can just use `margin: auto` in your CSS, like What I did in this snippet, you had a problem in also in your CSS for using `-200px` for margin-top.

```css
.bg-image {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/vKb4qnU.jpeg");
  width: 101%;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  filter: blur(4px);
  align-content: center;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top: 0;
}

.bg-text {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048);
  /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 100px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-image"></div>
<div class="bg-text">
  <h1>Project PP </h1>
</div>
```